# How to write AGOL data into an Excel sheet using FME

Tags: arcgis-online, fme-form, excel

I am using the AGOL feature service reader to read in the data and then writing to an Excel file. In the Excel writer parameters I have set the template file and sheet and set the mode to "update". When running I get the message "Excel Writer: Feature is in writer mode 'UPDATE' but has no value for row ID attribute 'xlsx_row_id'". What is "xlsx_row_id" and where do I need to be creating this attribute?

Comment: we need more info on your attributes - ArcGIS normally has fid (feature id) you need to expose that and use that as row_id for excel in order to the update correctly. (fid=row_id)

Comment: please show your fme workspace as is.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is treated as a database. So when you choose for "update" you will need to tell the writer which row must be updated.

You only want to update the file where you want to insert rows in Excel from the feature service. Change "update" to "insert" and you are good to go.